# tomcat java file when deploying

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

It's my first time deploying a JSP application using Mochahost with enabled tomcat.

I'm having trouble placing my `.java` files, where all `.jsp` files work fine under my domain's folder, but `.java` files are not found by tomcat.

I've placed them in the `work` folder, with `.jsp` files, even in the `public_html`, but neither places work.

I don't know if I need to change the action path in the `.jsp` page, or change the java files' path.

Comment: Your application needs to be packaged as a `war` file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format). I suggest using something like maven to compile and package your application. You do not _ever_ deploy java files to Tomcat.

Comment: You have to create a war format. Which IDE are you using, do you have any dependency management tool like Maven which can generate war files for you?

Comment: No I didn't use maven, I'm using netbeans, there is a .war file in the dist folder, is that what you're talking about? and how to deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile `.java` files with `javac` (which will produce `.class` files) and they need to be in the `WEB-INF\classes` folder. While the `.jsp` files get compiled/translated on demand, that isn't the case for `.java` files.

Comment: I did create a classes folder in WEB-INF and place both .java and .class files. should I remove .java?

Comment: The .java files won't be processed by Tomcat at all. But they aren't pages, so you can't just refer to them by name - you have to define a servlet in the web.xml file. See a tutorial on Java servlets for more information.